from email_validate import validate ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validate'
I have a source code written in Python 3.10 (3.10.14 specifically) that has been used some time ago and runs in a virtual environment for the development environment that is configured on a MacBookAir with MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6, the code of is executed correctly. However, when rebuilding the virtual environment and installing the libraries (dependencies) I found that the email_validate library that is used by the Python code with Flask cannot be installed.
My source code in the development environment has the instruction
from email_validate import validate

however when the instruction is executed I get the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validate'
Basically this library could be installed with the pip3.10 install email_validate command in the development environment, but when I try to install the library the following message is returned:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement email_validate (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for email_validate
The curious thing about this situation is that the same source code is executed correctly on a Mac in a development environment that already had the library installed, in addition this code is executed in a production environment on a pythonanywhere.com server where even from the line from the python interpreter command I can import the email_validate library, so I assume that this library was installed on the mac as in pythonanywhere and for this reason it is available. But apparently this library is no longer available on PyPi.
15:00 ~ $ python --version
Python 3.10.5
15:00 ~ $ python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jul 22 2022, 17:09:35) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import email_validate
>>>

I have checked the library in PyPi and there is no distribution, apparently the library does not exist. There are options to install a new library, however it implies that I must update the source code. Does the email_validate library still exist or should I migrate to another library?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

There are multiple Python versions installed on PythonAnywhere, make sure your code runs with the same environment / Python version you installed the package for.
